# Single quotes in double quotes variable

Tags: python

I am trying to get single quoted string inside a string.

```
filters = {'Title': 'test'}

for key in filters:
    where.append(key + "=" + "'{}'".format(filters[key]))

where_clause = " AND ".join(where)
```

The above give me result: `where_clause = 'Title=\'test\''`
How can i get `where_clause="Title='test' "`

Comment: can you show us the contents of `filters` by editing your post.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Added filters content

Comment: Please provide more code and info. This is insufficient for us to be of help.

Comment: What is this supposed to be in the end? SQL? (Probably not.) And there's no appreciable difference between `'Title=\'test\''` and `"Title='test'"`; as Python string literals they're equivalent.

Comment: @pikk assuming `where = [ ]`, I am curiously getting `where_clause="Title='test' "` as output and not  `where_clause = 'Title=\'test\''`... I tried this in jupyter notebook...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with both previous comments. You provide too little information for us to help you.

However, it might already be a good idea to use f-strings instead of `.format()`
Your code would then look like this:

```py
for key in filters:
    where.append(f"{key}='{filters[key]}'")

where_clause = " AND ".join(where)
```

It might even fix your issue with the single quotes, but again, it's hard to tell when I don't know what `filters` looks like.

Comment: I agree with you that using f-strings is better but isn't format also giving the right result?

Comment: Yes, the result should be equivalent for as far as I know.